# Facebook not fetching the image for post

Tags: image, post, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post a message to a facebook page's feed. I am using the GwtFB Sdk.

> data.put("message", new JSONString(message));
>
> String href = link + pageid + "?sk=app_" + FBUtil.getAPP_ID();
>
> data.put("link", new JSONString(href));
>
> data.put("name", new JSONString(name));
>
> data.put("picture", new JSONString(serviceImageUrl + id));
>
> data.put("caption", new JSONString("Check out at the Store !"));
>
> data.put("description", new JSONString(desc));

converting the data to a javascript 'msg' object and posting using the code,

> fbCore.api("/" + pageId + "/feed", "post", msg, callback);

The message is getting posted however the image is not appearing on the wall. I have checked the url that is generated and when I try to access the url I am able to get the image in the browser.

I had tried to see the logs, and observed that facebook graph api never tries to get the image from the url and just posts the message.

I have looked into all the other discussions and questions but I have seen that calling the api with post always works with images. But not for me. :(

Note : Gwt Fb uses the standard Javascript SDK of Facebook in case you are wondering about that!!

Would appreciate your help ?

Comment: Found the solution for the issue. It was an issue with the Servlet serving the image being in a particular module, and being called in another module. Absolutely not related to anything Facebook API..